# Is there an online list of Perakim of Mishnayos arranged alphabetically?

Tags: minhag, mishna, aleph-bet-letters, sitting-shiva

There is a popular custom cited by [Chabad](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/371116/jewish/Mishnayot-Study-for-Mourners.htm) to recite Mishnayos which initialize the deceased’s name. While they note that many Siddurim and Mishnayos have a list which alphabetizes the Mishnayos by letter, I’m struggling to find such a list online. Does such a list exist?

Comment: While I tried asking this as impartially as possible, it should be obvious to those who’ve been active on the chat that this non-halachic question was prompted by my grandfather’s petirah this morning. May the learning that results be an aliya for his Neshamah.

Comment: המקום ינחם אתכם בתוך שאר אבלי ציון וירושלים!

Comment: A lot of lists go by perek, but often people just learn the first mishnah of the perek in public.  A list of individual _mishnayos_ by letter would be even nicer because you'll have more flexibility to pick a mishnah that you can relate to your grandfather's life.

Comment: @Heshy I actually haven’t seen such a list even in print by individual Mishnah. Even one by Perek would be helpful; I don’t have a print copy with me and I’m traveling today.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

My code to generate this list in python from the Sefaria API:

```
import collections, requests, json
masechtos = ['Berakhot', 'Peah', 'Demai', 'Kilayim', 'Sheviit', 'Terumot', 'Maasrot', 'Maaser Sheni', 'Challah', 'Orlah', 'Bikkurim', 'Shabbat', 'Eruvin', 'Pesachim', 'Shekalim', 'Yoma', 'Sukkah', 'Beitzah', 'Rosh Hashanah', 'Taanit', 'Megillah', 'Moed Katan', 'Chagigah', 'Yevamot', 'Ketubot', 'Nedarim', 'Nazir', 'Sotah', 'Gittin', 'Kiddushin', 'Bava Kamma', 'Bava Metzia', 'Bava Batra', 'Sanhedrin', 'Makkot', 'Shevuot', 'Eduyot', 'Avodah Zarah', 'Pirkei Avot', 'Horayot', 'Zevachim', 'Menachot', 'Chullin', 'Bekhorot', 'Arakhin', 'Temurah', 'Keritot', 'Meilah', 'Tamid', 'Middot', 'Kinnim', 'Kelim', 'Oholot', 'Negaim', 'Parah', 'Tahorot', 'Mikvaot', 'Niddah', 'Makhshirin', 'Zavim', 'Tevul Yom', 'Yadayim', 'Oktzin']

result = collections.defaultdict(list)

for masechta in masechtos:
    perek = "Mishnah "+masechta+" 1"
    perek = perek.replace("Mishnah Pirkei", "Pirkei")
    while perek is not None:
        print(perek)
        j = json.loads(b"".join((requests.get("http://www.sefaria.org/api/texts/"+perek))))
        for i, mishnah in enumerate(j["he"], start=1):
            firstletter = mishnah[0]
            #workaround for two mishnayos in Sotah
            if firstletter == "(":
                firstletter = mishnah.split(")")[1].lstrip(" ")[0]
            result[firstletter].append("{} {}".format(perek, i))
        perek = j["next"]

def selection(masechta, perek, mishnahnumber):
    return True
    #return int(mishnahnumber) == 1

for letter, mishnayos in sorted(result.items()):
    print(letter)
    currentmasechta = currentperek = currentstring = None
    for mishnah in mishnayos:
        masechta, perek, mishnahnumber = mishnah.rsplit(" ", 2)
        if not selection(masechta, perek, mishnahnumber): continue
        masechta = masechta.replace("Mishnah ", "")
        if masechta != currentmasechta:
            if currentstring: print(currentstring)
            currentmasechta = masechta
            currentperek = None
            currentstring = " " + masechta + " "
        if perek != currentperek:
            if currentperek is not None: currentstring += ", "
            currentstring += perek + ":"
            currentperek = perek
        else:
            currentstring += ","
        currentstring += mishnahnumber
    print(currentstring)
```

The result is:

```
א
 Berakhot 2:2, 5:1, 6:8, 8:1,6
 Peah 1:1,2, 2:2, 4:10, 5:3, 7:3,4, 8:5,7
 Kilayim 1:7,8, 2:8, 4:2, 6:1,5, 7:3,5, 8:4, 9:1,8,10
 Sheviit 1:2,3, 2:6, 3:7,8,9, 5:6, 6:5,6, 8:3,5,7,8, 9:4, 10:6
 Terumot 1:4,5,7,8,10, 2:1,2,4, 4:13, 6:5, 11:1,3
 Maasrot 1:5, 3:5
 Maaser Sheni 1:7, 3:2,7, 5:8
 Challah 1:3,4, 3:1, 4:2
 Orlah 1:3,4,5
 Bikkurim 1:3,4, 2:6, 3:11, 4:1
 Shabbat 1:9,10, 2:2, 3:3,6, 5:4, 7:2, 8:5, 9:1, 14:2,3, 15:1, 18:3, 19:6, 20:3, 24:3
 Eruvin 2:6, 4:8, 5:4,5,8,9, 6:2,3, 7:9, 8:3,7, 10:8
 Pesachim 1:1,2,7, 2:5,7,8, 3:1,6, 6:1,2,3, 7:2,12, 8:7,8, 9:2,6
 Shekalim 1:2,4,5, 2:4, 4:9, 5:1,2,3, 7:6, 8:8
 Yoma 1:6, 2:6, 3:1,3, 6:8, 7:3, 8:3
 Sukkah 3:5,8, 5:5
 Beitzah 2:7, 3:1,6,7,8, 4:2,3,4,5,7
 Rosh Hashanah 1:1,7,8, 2:1, 4:6
 Taanit 1:2, 2:7,9,10, 4:2,8
 Megillah 1:3,5,6,7,8,9,10,11, 3:2, 4:3
 Moed Katan 1:6,7, 2:4, 3:4,7,8
 Chagigah 2:1, 3:3
 Yevamot 2:4, 3:1, 4:11,13, 6:3, 7:1, 8:2,4, 10:5, 13:2, 15:5,7, 16:3,5,7
 Ketubot 1:10, 3:1,7, 4:12, 5:1,5, 11:1,2,4, 12:3, 13:3
 Nedarim 3:1, 4:1, 8:6, 11:6
 Nazir 2:2, 7:3,4
 Sotah 1:5, 2:4, 3:4, 4:1,4, 6:2, 7:1
 Gittin 1:4, 2:4,7, 4:3, 5:2,3, 6:7, 7:2,9, 8:2
 Kiddushin 4:5,11
 Bava Kamma 1:1, 2:4,6, 5:7, 7:7, 8:7, 10:9
 Bava Metzia 2:1,5,7,9,11, 3:3, 4:4,9,11, 5:1,4,6,7,10, 7:5, 9:12
 Bava Batra 1:6, 2:13,14, 3:5,8, 4:9, 5:6,11, 8:4, 10:4
 Sanhedrin 1:5, 2:5, 3:2, 4:1, 5:3,5, 6:5, 7:1,4, 10:4, 11:1,4
 Makkot 1:4,6, 2:1, 3:11
 Shevuot 1:3,7, 2:2, 3:5,8, 4:11, 5:4, 6:4, 7:6, 8:1,2,4,5
 Eduyot 1:6,12, 2:2,3,10, 3:2,7,9,11, 4:1,12, 5:5, 8:6,7
 Avodah Zarah 1:5,7,9, 2:1,3,5,6,7, 5:7,9
 Pirkei Avot 1:3,11, 2:6,9, 4:20, 5:10,11,12,13,14,15, 6:2,5,9
 Horayot 2:3,4,5,7
 Zevachim 4:3, 5:1, 8:3,4,5, 9:3, 10:8, 11:4,7, 13:4, 14:10
 Menachot 1:2, 5:6, 6:1, 8:2, 11:2,6
 Chullin 2:9, 3:1,5, 5:1, 9:2
 Bekhorot 1:4,5, 2:8, 6:6,12, 7:7, 8:6,8,10
 Arakhin 2:1,2,3,5,6, 4:2,3, 6:3,5, 7:1,2, 8:2,3
 Temurah 1:3,4,5, 3:1, 6:2,3, 7:3
 Keritot 1:4,5, 2:1,2,5, 3:1,2,7,10, 5:3, 6:2
 Meilah 1:3, 5:3,5
 Tamid 3:1,2,3, 5:1,2
 Middot 1:2, 3:4
 Kinnim 3:2
 Kelim 1:1, 4:3, 10:1, 12:6, 15:2, 23:2, 26:5, 27:6, 30:2
 Oholot 1:4,5,6, 2:1,3,5, 3:5, 5:2, 6:1, 8:3,4,5, 9:15, 10:1,2,4,5,6, 11:2, 13:5,6, 14:7, 18:8
 Negaim 1:3, 2:2, 6:6,8, 7:1, 8:8, 12:6
 Parah 8:6, 9:7,9, 11:8, 12:5
 Tahorot 4:7, 5:2, 6:2,3, 7:4, 8:5,7
 Mikvaot 7:2, 8:1,2, 9:1,3,5, 10:3,4,8
 Niddah 1:4,5,7, 2:3,7, 5:8, 9:2,7
 Makhshirin 6:6,7
 Zavim 5:12
 Tevul Yom 4:1
 Yadayim 4:6,7,8
 Oktzin 1:3,4, 3:12
ב
 Berakhot 1:3,4, 3:4, 6:2,5, 8:2,3,4,5,8, 9:3
 Peah 4:2, 5:4, 6:1
 Demai 6:6
 Kilayim 2:2, 8:2
 Sheviit 4:1, 5:1,8, 6:3
 Terumot 3:4, 4:6, 6:2, 7:2, 10:1,12
 Maaser Sheni 2:7, 3:13, 4:3, 5:10
 Challah 4:11
 Orlah 2:17, 3:1
 Bikkurim 3:7
 Shabbat 1:5,6,7,8, 2:1, 4:1, 5:1, 6:1, 21:3
 Eruvin 1:7, 3:1, 6:5, 7:10, 8:6, 10:7
 Pesachim 3:2
 Shekalim 1:1,3, 3:1,2, 7:3,4,5, 8:6
 Yoma 1:7,8, 2:1, 3:7,8,9,10, 4:4,5,6, 6:2,7, 7:1
 Sukkah 1:10, 3:12, 5:2,7
 Beitzah 1:1,3,5,6,7,9, 2:4,5, 3:3,4,5
 Rosh Hashanah 1:2,5, 2:2, 3:4, 4:3,4
 Taanit 1:3, 4:1
 Megillah 2:3, 3:1,5,6, 4:2
 Moed Katan 3:9
 Chagigah 1:2, 2:3,7
 Yevamot 1:4, 7:2,3, 9:4,5,6, 10:6,7,8,9, 13:1, 15:2,3
 Ketubot 1:1,2,4, 4:11
 Nedarim 10:5, 11:12
 Nazir 5:1
 Sotah 1:7, 2:3, 3:7, 5:2,3,4,5, 7:5,6,7, 8:7, 9:14
 Gittin 2:3, 4:2, 8:4, 9:10
 Kiddushin 1:4, 4:6
 Bava Kamma 5:6
 Bava Batra 7:2, 8:3
 Sanhedrin 6:4, 8:1,5
 Makkot 1:5
 Eduyot 1:7, 4:2,3,8, 5:7
 Avodah Zarah 5:6
 Pirkei Avot 4:1,2, 5:1,22,23
 Zevachim 4:1, 11:5,8, 14:5,6,7,8
 Chullin 4:1,3,4,6, 5:4, 6:7, 8:4, 9:6, 10:3
 Bekhorot 5:2, 6:7
 Arakhin 3:2,3,4,5, 9:7
 Meilah 1:2
 Tamid 1:1, 2:5, 3:7, 7:1,2,3
 Middot 1:1,8
 Kinnim 1:3, 3:1
 Kelim 1:9, 8:6,9, 10:2, 11:4, 27:5, 28:8
 Oholot 6:6, 9:3,5,7,14, 15:4,6,7
 Negaim 2:1, 4:5,6,7,8,9,10,11, 6:2,3,4,5, 7:3, 8:2,3, 11:4,12, 12:2,7, 13:3,4,6, 14:2,3,7,8
 Parah 3:3, 5:5,6, 8:11
 Tahorot 6:8, 10:8
 Mikvaot 3:3, 10:6
 Niddah 4:1,2, 5:4,5,6,9, 6:1, 10:6
 Zavim 2:2, 5:11
 Tevul Yom 2:5,8, 4:5
 Yadayim 1:2, 4:1,2,3,4
 Oktzin 2:6
ג
 Peah 5:1
 Demai 6:10
 Kilayim 5:4
 Sheviit 3:6
 Terumot 9:4, 11:5
 Maasrot 3:9
 Challah 3:6
 Shabbat 20:4
 Eruvin 8:8, 9:2
 Yevamot 13:11
 Nazir 6:10
 Gittin 8:10, 9:3,8
 Bava Kamma 6:6, 7:2,3,4, 9:2
 Bava Batra 10:1,2
 Sanhedrin 3:7, 8:3
 Shevuot 5:5
 Avodah Zarah 4:10, 5:11
 Pirkei Avot 6:6,7
 Chullin 7:1,5, 10:4
 Kelim 2:6
 Negaim 6:1
 Tahorot 9:2
 Mikvaot 5:6, 6:6
 Yadayim 3:4
ד
 Kilayim 3:7
 Terumot 10:8, 11:2
 Orlah 2:5
 Bikkurim 2:7
 Shabbat 8:4
 Rosh Hashanah 2:8
 Nedarim 6:4, 10:4
 Nazir 5:2
 Sanhedrin 1:1,4, 3:1, 4:2, 10:3
 Avodah Zarah 4:9
 Zevachim 8:6,8, 11:1
 Chullin 6:5,6
 Arakhin 5:2
 Keritot 5:1
 Meilah 3:4
 Kelim 7:2, 12:7
 Parah 11:3
 Mikvaot 6:2
 Niddah 4:3, 7:1
 Oktzin 3:8
ה
 Berakhot 2:1,3,4, 3:5, 4:5,6, 5:3,4,5, 6:4,6,7, 9:1,4
 Peah 2:3,5, 3:2,3,4,5,7,8, 4:1,7, 5:5,6,7,8, 6:2,6,8,11, 7:5,8
 Demai 1:1,2,3,4, 2:2,3,4, 3:2,3,4,5,6, 4:1,2,5,6,7, 5:1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8, 6:1,2,5,11, 7:1,4,5,6
 Kilayim 1:1,2,3,5,6,9, 2:3,5,6,7,9, 3:3,4,6, 4:5,6,7,8,9, 5:5,6,7,8, 6:3,4,8,9, 7:1,2,4,6,7, 8:3,5, 9:2,7,9
 Sheviit 1:4,7, 2:7,9,10, 3:4,10, 4:4,5,6,8, 5:2,7, 7:6, 8:4, 9:1,5,6, 10:2,8,9
 Terumot 2:3, 3:1,3,5,6,8,9, 4:1,4,5, 6:1,3,4, 7:1,3, 8:1,3,7, 9:1,6,7, 10:3, 11:8
 Maasrot 1:3,6,7,8, 2:1,2,3,5,6,7,8, 3:1,2,3,6,7, 4:1,3,5, 5:1,2,5,6
 Maaser Sheni 1:3,4,5,6, 2:8,9, 3:8,10,12, 4:1,5,7,8,10,11,12, 5:13
 Challah 1:2,6,9, 2:3,4,5, 3:3,7,8,10
 Orlah 1:1,7, 2:1,2,3, 3:2,3
 Bikkurim 1:6,7,8,11, 2:1, 3:3,4,5,8
 Shabbat 2:5, 3:5, 6:8,9, 7:4, 8:1,2, 9:5,7, 10:1,2,3,4,5,6, 11:1,3,4,5,6, 12:1,2,3,4,6, 13:2,3, 14:4, 17:6, 20:5, 21:2, 22:5
 Eruvin 1:2,3,5, 4:6, 6:1,7, 8:4,5, 9:4, 10:1,3
 Pesachim 2:4, 3:7, 5:2,4,5, 6:5, 7:7,9,10, 8:1,2,3,4,6, 9:4,7,8, 10:3,9
 Shekalim 1:7, 2:2,3, 4:1,6,7,8, 6:6
 Yoma 2:3,4, 3:6, 5:1,4,6, 7:2, 8:2,4,9
 Sukkah 1:2,4,8,9,11, 2:1,2,3,4, 3:2, 4:8, 5:1
 Beitzah 1:2,8, 2:9, 4:1, 5:3,4,5
 Rosh Hashanah 3:7, 4:7
 Taanit 1:4,5, 3:9
 Megillah 2:1,4, 4:1,4,5,8,9
 Moed Katan 1:8, 3:5
 Chagigah 1:1,8, 2:6, 3:6,7
 Yevamot 2:9,10, 3:2,3, 4:1,2,7,8,10,12, 6:1, 7:4,5, 8:1,5, 10:1,3, 11:2,4,7, 12:4, 13:4,5,6,13, 14:2, 15:1,4,6,8, 16:1
 Ketubot 1:3,5,6,7,9, 2:1,3,5,9, 3:4,9, 4:2,3,4,6, 5:3,4,6,7,8, 6:2,5,7, 7:1,2,3,4,5,7,8,9, 8:1,7, 9:1,3,4,6,7,8,9, 10:3, 11:6, 12:1, 13:4,5,6,8,11
 Nedarim 1:2,3,4, 3:5,6,7,8,9,10, 4:2,4,5,6,7,8, 5:1,2,3,4,6, 6:1,2,5,6,7,8,9, 7:1,2,3,4,5,7, 8:7, 10:7,8, 11:8
 Nazir 1:2,4,5,6,7, 2:1,4,5,6,7,8,9,10, 3:4, 4:2,3,4,6,7, 5:5,6, 6:9, 9:1,3
 Sotah 1:1,4,6, 2:1,2,6, 3:1,2
 Gittin 1:1,3,6, 2:1,5, 3:2,3,5,6,7,8, 4:1,6,7,8,9, 5:1,5, 6:1,2,4,5, 7:5,6,7,8, 8:1,7,9, 9:1,2
 Kiddushin 1:1,8, 2:1,2,4,5,6,7,8,9,10, 3:1,2,5,6,10, 4:4,8
 Bava Kamma 2:3, 3:1,2,3,7, 5:2,3,5, 6:1,2,3,4,5, 7:6, 8:1,3,5,6, 9:1,4,5,8,9,10,11, 10:1,3,5,6,7,8
 Bava Metzia 1:2,3, 3:1,2,6,7,9,10,11,12, 4:1,3,7,12, 5:2, 6:1,2,3,4,5,7,8, 7:1,3,4,7, 8:1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9, 9:1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,13, 10:1,2,3
 Bava Batra 1:1,3, 3:4,6, 4:1,3,4,5,6,7,8, 5:1,2,3,4,5,7,8,9,10, 6:1,2,3,4,8, 7:1,4, 8:5,6,7,8, 9:2,3,4,5,7, 10:8
 Sanhedrin 2:2, 3:5, 5:1, 6:2,3, 7:5,6,7,8,9,10,11, 8:4,6, 9:6, 10:5, 11:6
 Makkot 1:9, 2:2,3, 3:2,3,4,5,6,8
 Shevuot 5:3, 6:7, 7:2,3, 8:3,6
 Eduyot 1:3,9,10, 2:9, 3:5,6, 4:4,7,10, 6:2, 7:1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9, 8:1,2,3,4,5
 Avodah Zarah 3:2,3,5, 4:11,12, 5:1,4,5,12
 Pirkei Avot 1:12,13,14, 2:3,4,5,7,10,16, 3:10,14,15,16, 4:3,8,17,22, 5:21, 6:3
 Horayot 1:1,2,3,4,5, 2:1,2, 3:7
 Zevachim 1:3,4, 2:2, 3:3,4,5, 4:4, 5:4,6,8, 8:9,10,11, 9:1, 10:3,4, 12:6, 13:1,5,6,7,8, 14:2
 Menachot 2:1,3,4, 3:1,5, 4:1,2,3,4, 5:8,9, 6:6,7, 7:1,2,3,5, 8:5, 9:8, 10:6,7, 11:5, 12:1,2,3, 13:1,3,4,5,6,7,8,10
 Chullin 1:1,2,3,4,7, 2:1,2,3,5,6,7,8,10, 4:2,5,7, 5:3, 6:2, 7:3, 9:1,3,7,8, 10:1, 12:3,4
 Bekhorot 1:1,6, 2:1,4, 3:1, 4:3,5,6,7,8,9,10, 5:3,4,6, 7:2,3,6, 8:9, 9:3,4
 Arakhin 1:1,2,3,4, 4:1, 5:1,4, 6:2,4, 7:3,4,5, 8:1,5, 9:1,3,4
 Temurah 1:1,6, 3:3, 4:2,3,4, 5:3,4,5,6
 Keritot 1:6,7, 2:4, 3:6, 6:1,5,6,7
 Meilah 2:4,8,9, 3:2, 4:4,6, 5:1, 6:1,5
 Tamid 2:2,3, 5:6, 6:1, 7:4
 Middot 2:1, 3:1,6, 4:4
 Kinnim 3:6
 Kelim 2:2,3,7,8, 3:5, 4:1, 6:1,2, 7:1,4, 8:1,2,7,11, 9:3,6, 10:4, 11:3, 12:8, 13:1,7, 14:3,4,5, 16:2,3,7, 17:2,3,4,5,9,15, 18:1,3, 19:1,2,8, 20:1, 21:1,2,3, 22:1,2,10, 23:1,4,5, 25:2,4, 27:1,2,3,4,7, 28:3
 Oholot 1:7, 2:4,6, 4:3, 5:3,5, 7:1,3,4,6, 8:2, 9:2,4,6,8,9,10,11,12,13, 10:7, 11:1,4,5,6,8, 13:1,3,4, 14:1, 15:10, 16:3,4,5, 17:1,2,3, 18:6,7,9
 Negaim 1:2, 3:1,4,5,6,7,8, 5:2, 7:4, 8:1,7,9, 9:1,2, 10:1,3,10, 11:3,5,8,9, 13:2,5,7,10, 14:9
 Parah 2:5, 5:1,2,7, 6:1,2,3,5, 7:2,3,5,6,7,8,10,12, 8:2,3,4,9, 9:4, 10:2,4,5, 12:1,2,4,6,7,9
 Tahorot 1:2,5, 2:1,3,4,5,6,8, 3:1, 4:1,2,3, 5:1,4, 6:7,9,10, 7:1,2,3,5,6,7,9, 8:1,2,3,4, 9:4,5,6,8, 10:1,2,3,4,5,7
 Mikvaot 2:1,6,7,8,9, 4:1,2,3,5, 5:2,5, 6:4,5,10,11, 7:3,7, 8:3, 10:2
 Niddah 3:1,2,3,4,5,6,7, 4:4,6, 5:2, 6:13,14, 7:2, 8:1, 9:1,3,9,10, 10:3,4,5,8
 Makhshirin 1:2,3,4,5,6, 2:4,10, 3:3,4,5,6,7,8, 4:1,3,9, 5:2,4,6,7,10,11, 6:1,2
 Zavim 1:1,2, 2:1,3,4, 3:1,3, 4:2,3,6,7, 5:1,5,6,7,8,9,10
 Tevul Yom 1:1,2,4,5, 2:3,4, 4:2,6,7
 Yadayim 1:3,4,5, 2:3, 3:1
 Oktzin 2:3,5, 3:2,4,5,6,7
ו
 Berakhot 2:7
 Peah 1:5, 2:1,4, 6:4
 Demai 2:1
 Kilayim 1:4
 Sheviit 7:2,7, 8:10, 9:3
 Terumot 1:9, 2:6, 3:7, 4:10, 8:2,10,11,12, 9:2,3, 11:7
 Maasrot 1:4
 Maaser Sheni 5:5
 Challah 4:9
 Orlah 2:6
 Bikkurim 1:9,10, 2:4
 Shabbat 1:4, 5:3, 7:3, 16:4
 Eruvin 2:5, 3:8, 4:9, 5:3, 8:11
 Pesachim 1:5, 2:6, 3:8, 10:8
 Shekalim 1:6, 6:3
 Yoma 3:2,11, 5:5, 6:4
 Sukkah 3:9
 Beitzah 2:3
 Rosh Hashanah 2:4, 3:8, 4:2
 Taanit 2:3, 3:3,4, 4:3
 Megillah 3:3
 Moed Katan 2:2, 3:1,2,3
 Yevamot 3:8, 6:2, 9:2
 Ketubot 2:2,7,10, 3:2, 7:6,10
 Nedarim 2:1, 4:3, 5:5, 9:2,4, 11:1,2,9
 Nazir 6:2
 Sotah 1:3,9, 4:2,5, 7:2, 8:2,3,4,5,6
 Gittin 5:8, 8:3
 Kiddushin 4:2
 Bava Metzia 2:2,6, 3:5, 5:11, 7:2, 10:4
 Bava Batra 1:2
 Sanhedrin 2:4, 3:3,4, 4:4, 5:4, 8:7, 9:1, 10:6
 Makkot 2:5, 3:1,14
 Shevuot 1:4,6, 2:4, 4:2, 6:5, 7:4,5,8
 Eduyot 1:4,5
 Avodah Zarah 1:3,8
 Horayot 3:4
 Zevachim 7:3, 9:2,5,6, 10:2,7
 Menachot 5:4, 8:6
 Chullin 3:2,3,4,7, 11:2
 Arakhin 2:4
 Temurah 3:2,4, 4:1, 7:4,5
 Keritot 3:3,8,9
 Meilah 3:1
 Middot 1:5,6,9, 2:6, 3:2,5,8, 4:2,3,5,6
 Kelim 17:11,12,14, 27:8
 Negaim 12:3
 Parah 3:6
 Tahorot 1:4
 Niddah 1:6, 8:2, 10:7
 Zavim 5:2
ז
 Berakhot 3:6
 Peah 7:2
 Kilayim 2:4
 Sheviit 4:9, 10:4
 Terumot 7:4,7, 10:7
 Eruvin 10:4
 Pesachim 8:5
 Beitzah 1:4
 Taanit 4:5
 Ketubot 2:4
 Sotah 9:6
 Gittin 7:3
 Bava Kamma 3:5, 8:2, 10:4
 Bava Metzia 7:9
 Sanhedrin 11:2
 Zevachim 2:3, 5:5
 Bekhorot 6:11
 Oholot 14:2,4
 Tahorot 9:1
 Makhshirin 2:1
 Zavim 4:4
 Oktzin 2:1
ח
 Berakhot 2:5,8, 9:5
 Peah 4:11
 Demai 6:9
 Kilayim 5:3
 Sheviit 4:3
 Terumot 1:1,2,6, 8:8,9, 10:9
 Maasrot 5:7
 Challah 1:1, 2:6
 Orlah 2:16
 Shabbat 5:2, 8:7, 18:2, 22:1
 Eruvin 6:6,8, 7:1,3, 8:9, 9:3
 Pesachim 2:2, 6:4, 7:4, 9:9
 Yoma 8:8
 Sukkah 1:5, 5:4,8
 Beitzah 2:2
 Rosh Hashanah 2:5
 Taanit 4:6
 Chagigah 3:1,4
 Yevamot 1:1, 5:5,6, 11:3, 12:2,3,5, 14:1
 Sotah 7:4
 Gittin 5:7
 Bava Kamma 1:4, 8:4
 Bava Metzia 4:8
 Bava Batra 3:1
 Sanhedrin 11:3
 Eduyot 4:6
 Pirkei Avot 5:9, 6:10
 Horayot 3:3
 Zevachim 5:3, 6:2,4,7, 7:1, 8:12, 11:2, 13:3
 Menachot 4:5, 9:9, 11:3
 Chullin 5:2, 6:3, 8:6
 Bekhorot 1:3, 6:3,4, 8:7
 Arakhin 5:3,6, 8:6
 Temurah 2:2,3
 Keritot 2:3, 5:4,5,6,7,8, 6:4
 Meilah 2:1,5, 3:5, 4:2
 Middot 1:3
 Kinnim 1:1,2, 2:5, 3:3,4,5
 Kelim 3:2,3,4,8, 4:2, 5:8,10, 9:2,5, 10:5,6, 13:3, 20:2, 29:3,4,5,6
 Oholot 9:16, 13:2, 15:3,5,8,9
 Negaim 3:2, 11:6
 Parah 1:4, 3:2, 7:1
 Tahorot 3:6
 Niddah 2:6
 Makhshirin 3:2, 4:4, 6:8
 Tevul Yom 2:6,7, 3:3
 Oktzin 3:9,11
ט
 Shabbat 4:2
 Yoma 4:1
 Zevachim 12:1, 13:2
 Chullin 8:3
 Kelim 12:1
 Oholot 3:7, 6:5, 15:2
 Negaim 13:8
 Parah 12:11
 Tahorot 3:3
 Tevul Yom 3:6
י
 Demai 6:4
 Terumot 8:4
 Maaser Sheni 5:15
 Challah 4:7
 Orlah 2:12
 Bikkurim 1:1, 2:2,3
 Shabbat 1:1, 6:5,6,10, 13:7, 15:2
 Pesachim 5:7
 Yoma 8:1
 Sukkah 3:13, 5:6
 Beitzah 2:1
 Rosh Hashanah 4:1
 Taanit 3:2
 Chagigah 1:4, 2:2
 Yevamot 9:1, 13:12
 Ketubot 3:6, 6:6
 Nedarim 2:3, 11:7
 Sotah 9:10
 Gittin 5:4, 9:9
 Bava Kamma 3:10
 Bava Metzia 3:8
 Bava Batra 8:1
 Makkot 3:9,13
 Shevuot 2:1
 Avodah Zarah 5:2,8,10
 Pirkei Avot 1:4,5,6,8, 5:20
 Zevachim 1:2
 Menachot 5:3,5
 Chullin 5:5, 7:4
 Bekhorot 2:9, 8:1,2, 9:8
 Arakhin 3:1, 9:8
 Temurah 2:1, 5:2, 7:1,2
 Keritot 1:3, 3:4,5
 Kelim 3:6, 15:3
 Oholot 7:5, 8:1, 14:6
 Negaim 4:1,2,3, 8:10
 Parah 2:3
 Mikvaot 7:1
 Niddah 5:1
 Tevul Yom 3:2,5
 Oktzin 3:1
כ
 Berakhot 6:1, 7:3
 Peah 1:4, 4:8, 7:1,6,7
 Demai 6:3
 Kilayim 2:1,10, 3:2, 5:1,2, 8:1
 Sheviit 7:1, 8:1, 9:7, 10:7
 Terumot 4:9, 10:10, 11:9
 Maasrot 1:1
 Maaser Sheni 2:4, 4:9, 5:1,2,3,4,11
 Challah 3:4,9
 Orlah 2:4,13, 3:8
 Bikkurim 2:8,9,10,11, 3:1,2, 4:2,3,4,5
 Shabbat 2:3, 3:1, 7:1, 11:2, 12:5, 16:1,7, 17:1,5,8, 22:2
 Eruvin 5:1, 7:2,6,8, 8:1,2, 9:1, 10:14
 Pesachim 2:1, 3:3, 4:2, 5:8,9, 7:1,11
 Shekalim 8:1,2
 Yoma 1:2,4, 5:7, 7:5
 Sukkah 2:9, 4:6,10
 Beitzah 5:2
 Rosh Hashanah 2:3,6, 3:2
 Taanit 2:8, 4:4
 Megillah 1:2, 2:5,6, 4:7
 Chagigah 3:2,8
 Yevamot 1:2, 2:1,3, 4:4, 5:2,4, 6:4,5, 7:6, 11:5
 Ketubot 3:5,8, 9:5, 12:4
 Nedarim 1:1, 9:7
 Nazir 1:1, 7:1, 9:4
 Sotah 1:2, 5:1
 Gittin 1:5, 3:1, 8:5,6,8
 Kiddushin 1:6,7,9,10, 3:12, 4:3
 Bava Kamma 1:2, 2:1,2
 Bava Metzia 4:2,5,10, 6:6, 7:11
 Bava Batra 1:4,5, 3:3, 10:3
 Sanhedrin 2:1, 3:6,8, 4:5, 5:2, 10:1
 Makkot 1:1, 2:8, 3:10,12,15
 Shevuot 1:2, 4:4, 7:1,7
 Eduyot 1:8,11,14, 3:1,4, 4:5, 6:3
 Avodah Zarah 3:1,10, 4:5
 Pirkei Avot 5:16,17,18,19, 6:4,11
 Horayot 2:6, 3:1,2,5,6,8
 Zevachim 1:1, 2:1,4, 3:1, 4:2, 6:3, 8:1, 9:4,7, 10:1,5,6, 11:6, 12:2,4, 14:9
 Menachot 1:1,4, 5:1,2, 6:3,4,5, 8:1, 9:5,6,7, 10:3, 11:4
 Chullin 1:5,6, 6:1, 8:1, 10:2
 Bekhorot 2:2,3, 5:1, 9:6,7
 Arakhin 9:5
 Temurah 5:1, 6:1,5, 7:6
 Keritot 2:6, 4:2
 Meilah 3:6, 4:3,5
 Middot 2:2,4, 5:1
 Kinnim 1:4, 2:2
 Kelim 2:1,5, 4:4, 5:2, 7:3,6, 11:1,2, 12:3, 14:1,6,7, 15:1,4, 16:1,4, 17:1,6,7,8,13, 18:7, 20:5, 22:4,5,6,7,9, 25:1,6,7,8,9, 26:2,3,7, 28:5,9, 30:1,3
 Oholot 1:2,3, 3:1,4,6, 5:6,7, 6:3,4,7, 7:2, 9:1, 11:7,9, 12:8, 16:1,2, 18:1,5
 Negaim 1:5,6, 2:3,4,5, 5:1,4, 8:4,5, 10:5, 11:1,11, 12:1,5, 14:1
 Parah 1:3, 3:9,11, 4:4, 8:5,7,8, 10:1, 11:2,4,5,6,7, 12:10
 Tahorot 1:6,9, 3:4,5, 4:4, 6:4, 8:6
 Mikvaot 3:2, 5:4, 6:1,9, 10:1,5,7
 Niddah 1:2, 2:1,4, 4:5,7, 6:2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10, 7:3,4, 9:8
 Makhshirin 1:1, 5:9, 6:3
 Tevul Yom 3:1
 Yadayim 3:2
 Oktzin 1:1,5, 2:2,4,10, 3:10
ל
 Peah 1:6
 Sheviit 3:5, 5:3,4, 7:4,5
 Maasrot 5:3,4
 Maaser Sheni 3:1, 5:12
 Orlah 2:7
 Bikkurim 3:12
 Shabbat 1:2,3, 2:4, 6:2,3,4, 23:3
 Eruvin 1:6, 10:5,6,9
 Sukkah 3:1, 4:1,2
 Yevamot 6:6
 Ketubot 4:5,7,8,10, 8:8
 Gittin 5:6, 7:4
 Kiddushin 4:12,13
 Bava Metzia 5:9
 Bava Batra 2:1,2,3,12, 3:7, 4:2
 Makkot 2:4
 Shevuot 6:3
 Avodah Zarah 1:1, 3:8, 4:8
 Zevachim 2:5, 4:6, 6:6
 Menachot 3:2, 8:7
 Chullin 12:5
 Bekhorot 1:7
 Meilah 2:7
 Tamid 4:1,2
 Middot 2:3, 3:3
 Kinnim 2:3
 Kelim 1:2,3,4,8, 10:8
 Oholot 5:4
 Parah 3:4,5,7, 10:6, 12:8
 Mikvaot 1:6,7,8, 9:4
 Tevul Yom 4:4
מ
 Berakhot 1:1,2,5, 3:1, 5:2, 8:7
 Peah 2:6, 3:1, 4:9, 8:1,6,8,9
 Demai 3:1, 4:4, 5:9, 7:2,7,8
 Kilayim 4:4, 9:3,5
 Sheviit 2:2,3,4, 3:1, 4:7,10, 5:5,9, 6:4, 8:11, 9:8,9
 Terumot 4:2, 9:5, 10:6, 11:6,10
 Maasrot 1:2, 3:4
 Maaser Sheni 1:1,2, 2:1,5,10, 3:3,5,9, 4:4,6, 5:7,9,14
 Orlah 3:6
 Bikkurim 1:2
 Shabbat 1:11, 3:4, 9:2,3,4, 15:3, 16:2,3, 18:1, 19:3,4, 23:2,4, 24:1,2,4,5
 Eruvin 1:1,9,10, 2:2, 3:2,5, 4:1,3,4,5,7,10,11, 5:7, 6:4, 7:5, 10:12,13
 Pesachim 4:1,3,4,5,7, 9:1,3,5, 10:2,4,7
 Shekalim 2:1,5, 4:3,4,5, 5:4,5, 6:2, 7:1,2
 Yoma 1:3,5, 2:2, 5:2, 6:3,6, 8:6,7
 Sukkah 1:6, 2:5,7, 3:10,11,15, 4:4,5,7, 5:3
 Beitzah 1:10, 3:2, 5:1,6,7
 Rosh Hashanah 1:6,9
 Taanit 1:1, 2:5, 3:6
 Megillah 1:1, 4:10
 Moed Katan 1:1,9, 2:1,3,5
 Chagigah 1:5,6, 3:5
 Yevamot 2:5,6,8, 4:5, 10:4, 11:6, 12:1,6, 13:8,9, 16:6
 Ketubot 6:1, 9:2, 10:1,2,4,5,6, 11:3, 13:2,7
 Nedarim 6:3,10, 10:2
 Nazir 2:3, 3:1,2,3,5,6,7, 4:1, 5:3,4, 6:11
 Sotah 3:8, 4:3, 6:1, 7:3, 8:1, 9:4,9,11,12,15
 Gittin 4:5, 5:9, 6:6, 7:1
 Kiddushin 3:9, 4:9,10
 Bava Kamma 4:9, 7:1,5, 10:10
 Bava Metzia 1:5,6,7,8, 2:3,4,8,10, 5:3,8, 7:10, 10:5
 Bava Batra 2:4,5,7,8,9,10,11, 6:5,6,7, 7:3, 9:1, 10:5,6
 Sanhedrin 1:2, 2:3, 7:2,3, 8:2, 9:4,5
 Makkot 1:2,3,8,10
 Shevuot 4:5,6,7,8,9,13, 6:2
 Eduyot 1:13, 3:3, 4:11
 Avodah Zarah 1:6, 2:2, 3:6, 4:2
 Pirkei Avot 1:1
 Zevachim 7:5,6, 14:3
 Menachot 6:2, 7:6, 9:4, 10:2,5, 12:4,5, 13:2
 Bekhorot 4:4, 6:9, 7:1, 8:3, 9:1,2
 Arakhin 8:4,7, 9:2
 Temurah 1:2
 Keritot 6:8
 Meilah 1:4
 Tamid 1:2,4, 3:5,6,8,9, 5:3,4,5, 6:2,3
 Middot 4:7, 5:2
 Kelim 3:7, 5:5, 8:10, 9:1, 10:3, 12:4,5, 13:4,5,8, 14:2,8, 18:2,4,5,6,9, 19:3,5,6,10, 20:3,7, 23:3, 25:3, 28:4,6
 Oholot 1:8, 3:2, 4:1, 10:3
 Negaim 1:1, 5:5, 7:5, 10:8,9, 13:9,11, 14:6,11,12
 Parah 7:9, 8:10, 9:5,6,8, 11:9
 Tahorot 1:7,8, 5:7, 6:1, 7:8, 8:9, 10:6
 Mikvaot 1:2,5, 2:2,5,10, 3:4, 4:4, 5:1,3, 6:8, 7:6, 9:7
 Niddah 2:5, 5:7, 8:3
 Makhshirin 2:2,6,7,8,9, 4:2, 5:1
 Zavim 3:2, 5:3,4
 Tevul Yom 1:3, 2:1
 Yadayim 1:1
נ
 Berakhot 3:3, 7:2
 Peah 1:3, 4:3, 8:2,3,4
 Kilayim 3:5
 Terumot 3:2, 7:6, 8:6
 Challah 1:7, 3:2,5, 4:6,10
 Orlah 1:6
 Shabbat 16:6,8, 17:2, 20:2, 21:1, 22:4
 Eruvin 3:3,4, 5:2, 7:4,7,11, 10:10,11
 Pesachim 2:3, 7:5,6,8
 Yoma 5:3
 Sukkah 2:8, 4:9
 Chagigah 2:5
 Yevamot 5:3, 10:2, 11:1, 15:9,10, 16:4
 Ketubot 3:3, 4:1,9, 5:2,9, 8:3,5, 12:2
 Nedarim 2:5, 3:2,3,4, 10:1,3, 11:5
 Nazir 4:5, 6:4, 8:2, 9:2,5
 Sotah 3:6, 9:2,3,5,7
 Gittin 2:2
 Kiddushin 1:5
 Bava Kamma 9:3,6,7,12, 10:2
 Bava Batra 2:6, 9:8,9,10
 Sanhedrin 6:1,6, 9:2, 11:5
 Makkot 2:7, 3:7
 Shevuot 2:3, 3:6
 Avodah Zarah 2:4, 3:9, 5:3
 Pirkei Avot 1:7
 Zevachim 8:7, 11:3
 Menachot 3:4, 7:4, 13:11
 Chullin 7:6
 Bekhorot 4:2, 5:5, 6:5,8
 Temurah 6:4
 Meilah 5:2,4, 6:3,4
 Tamid 1:3, 3:4, 4:3
 Kelim 7:5, 8:8, 11:9, 15:6, 19:4, 25:5, 29:1
 Oholot 3:3, 12:1,3
 Negaim 7:2, 11:10, 13:12, 14:10
 Parah 3:10, 6:4, 9:2, 12:3
 Tahorot 1:3, 6:5, 9:3,9
 Mikvaot 1:3,4, 7:4, 8:4,5
 Niddah 2:2, 7:5, 9:11, 10:2
 Yadayim 2:1,2
 Oktzin 3:3
ס
 Peah 6:9
 Sheviit 2:5
 Terumot 4:11, 5:1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
 Maaser Sheni 2:6
 Orlah 3:9
 Shabbat 22:6
 Pesachim 7:3
 Shekalim 8:3
 Sukkah 1:1
 Rosh Hashanah 4:5,9
 Taanit 2:1, 3:1
 Yevamot 8:6
 Nedarim 2:4
 Nazir 1:3, 6:3
 Bava Batra 8:2
 Sanhedrin 1:3,6, 4:3
 Menachot 11:8
 Chullin 3:6
 Keritot 4:1
 Tamid 2:4
 Kelim 8:3, 9:4,7, 20:6, 22:3, 26:1,4, 27:9, 28:10
 Oholot 11:3, 12:2,4, 15:1
 Parah 3:8
 Tahorot 4:8,9,11,12,13, 6:6
 Mikvaot 2:3
 Yadayim 2:4, 3:5
ע
 Berakhot 6:3, 9:2
 Peah 4:6
 Demai 5:10, 6:12
 Kilayim 3:1, 6:2,7, 7:8
 Sheviit 1:1,6,8, 2:1, 3:2,3, 6:2, 8:9
 Terumot 11:4
 Maaser Sheni 5:6
 Challah 1:5,8, 2:2
 Orlah 1:2,8
 Bikkurim 3:6
 Shabbat 2:6, 8:3,6, 19:2, 23:5
 Eruvin 2:1, 5:6
 Pesachim 10:1,6
 Shekalim 7:7
 Yoma 6:5, 8:5
 Sukkah 3:3,6, 4:3
 Beitzah 2:10
 Rosh Hashanah 1:3,4
 Taanit 1:6,7, 2:2,4, 3:5,7,8
 Moed Katan 1:10
 Chagigah 1:3, 2:4
 Yevamot 8:3
 Nedarim 8:2,3,4,5
 Nazir 7:2
 Sotah 2:5, 3:3, 6:4, 9:1,8
 Gittin 4:4
 Kiddushin 1:2,3, 2:3, 3:3, 4:1
 Bava Metzia 4:6
 Makkot 1:7
 Shevuot 4:10
 Eduyot 5:6
 Avodah Zarah 1:4, 4:3,4,6
 Pirkei Avot 3:1, 5:2,3,4,5,6
 Zevachim 6:5, 7:2,4, 12:3, 14:4
 Chullin 9:4, 12:2
 Bekhorot 4:1, 6:1, 7:4
 Arakhin 9:6
 Keritot 1:2
 Meilah 2:2
 Middot 2:5
 Kelim 1:5,6,7, 5:3, 11:5, 13:6, 20:4, 26:6,8,9
 Oholot 2:7, 12:7, 18:10
 Negaim 3:3, 6:7, 12:4, 13:1
 Tahorot 4:5, 5:9, 8:8
 Mikvaot 6:7, 9:6
 Niddah 8:4
 Makhshirin 2:5, 4:5,10
 Zavim 4:5
 Tevul Yom 3:4, 4:3
 Oktzin 1:6, 2:7,8
פ
 Peah 4:4
 Demai 7:3
 Kilayim 6:6
 Sheviit 10:3,5
 Maasrot 2:4
 Maaser Sheni 3:4,6, 4:2
 Challah 2:1
 Shabbat 6:7, 9:6, 17:7
 Eruvin 4:2
 Shekalim 4:2, 8:4
 Yoma 2:7, 3:4
 Sukkah 1:3
 Yevamot 13:10
 Ketubot 6:3,4
 Nedarim 9:5,6,9
 Sotah 7:8
 Zevachim 5:2, 12:5, 14:1
 Menachot 2:5
 Bekhorot 1:2
 Meilah 2:3, 6:6
 Middot 3:7, 4:1
 Kelim 2:4, 11:6, 16:5, 28:2
 Parah 2:2, 4:1
 Makhshirin 2:11, 4:7, 5:3,5
צ
 Maaser Sheni 3:11
 Shabbat 13:6
 Moed Katan 1:4
 Chullin 8:2
 Kelim 30:4
 Negaim 11:2
 Parah 9:1, 11:1
ק
 Berakhot 3:2
 Peah 2:8, 6:7
 Kilayim 4:1
 Sheviit 7:3
 Terumot 1:3
 Challah 4:4
 Shabbat 17:3, 19:5
 Pesachim 5:10
 Yoma 3:5, 4:2, 7:4
 Megillah 1:4, 2:2, 4:6
 Nedarim 2:2, 3:11, 7:6, 8:1, 9:8,10, 11:3,4,11
 Gittin 2:6, 6:3
 Kiddushin 3:7,8,11
 Bava Metzia 7:6
 Zevachim 3:2, 4:5, 6:1, 8:2
 Menachot 10:4,8,9
 Chullin 8:5, 9:5
 Meilah 1:1, 3:8, 4:1
 Kinnim 2:1,4
 Kelim 8:4, 11:7,8, 12:2, 13:2, 16:6, 17:16
 Oholot 6:2, 12:5,6, 14:3
 Negaim 11:7
 Parah 5:3, 7:4, 10:3
 Mikvaot 9:2
 Makhshirin 4:6,8, 5:8
 Tevul Yom 2:2
 Oktzin 2:9
ר
 Berakhot 2:6, 4:2,3,4,7
 Peah 3:6, 6:3
 Demai 2:5, 4:3
 Kilayim 4:3
 Sheviit 2:8
 Terumot 4:7,8, 6:6, 10:11
 Maasrot 4:6
 Maaser Sheni 2:2
 Challah 2:8, 4:8
 Orlah 1:9
 Bikkurim 1:5, 3:9,10
 Shabbat 13:1,5, 16:5, 17:4, 19:1, 20:1
 Eruvin 1:4, 2:3,4, 3:6,7,9, 8:10, 10:2
 Pesachim 1:3,4,6, 3:4, 4:6, 10:5
 Shekalim 8:5,7
 Sukkah 2:6, 3:4,14
 Beitzah 4:6
 Rosh Hashanah 2:7, 3:1
 Megillah 3:4
 Moed Katan 1:2,3,5, 3:6
 Chagigah 1:7
 Yevamot 5:1, 13:3
 Ketubot 1:8, 2:8, 8:2,4
 Nedarim 9:1,3
 Nazir 5:7, 6:8
 Sotah 3:5, 9:13
 Gittin 1:2
 Kiddushin 3:4,13, 4:7,14
 Bava Metzia 1:4
 Sanhedrin 9:3
 Makkot 2:6, 3:16
 Shevuot 1:5, 2:5, 6:6
 Eduyot 2:1, 5:1,2,3,4, 6:1
 Avodah Zarah 1:2, 4:1
 Pirkei Avot 1:16,18, 2:1,2,8,11,12,13,14,15, 3:2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,11,12,13,17,18, 4:4,5,6,7,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,18,21, 6:8
 Menachot 1:3, 5:7, 9:3, 10:1
 Chullin 11:1
 Bekhorot 2:5,6, 3:2,3, 6:2,10
 Keritot 4:3, 5:2, 6:3,9
 Meilah 3:3
 Tamid 2:1
 Kelim 15:5, 17:10
 Oholot 2:2
 Negaim 1:4
 Parah 1:1,2, 2:1
 Tahorot 2:2,7, 3:2, 4:10, 9:7
 Mikvaot 2:4, 3:1
 Niddah 1:3
 Zavim 1:3,4,5,6, 4:1
 Yadayim 3:3
ש
 Berakhot 7:1,4,5
 Peah 2:7, 4:5, 5:2, 6:5
 Demai 6:7,8
 Kilayim 8:6
 Sheviit 1:5, 4:2, 6:1, 8:2, 9:2, 10:1
 Terumot 4:3,12, 7:5, 8:5
 Maasrot 4:4, 5:8
 Challah 2:7, 4:1,3,5
 Orlah 2:8,9,11,14, 3:7
 Shabbat 2:7, 13:4, 14:1, 22:3, 23:1
 Eruvin 1:8, 6:9,10, 10:15
 Pesachim 3:5, 4:8,9, 5:3,6, 6:6, 7:13, 9:10,11
 Shekalim 3:3, 5:6, 6:1,4,5
 Yoma 1:1, 4:3, 6:1
 Sukkah 3:7
 Beitzah 2:6,8
 Rosh Hashanah 2:9, 3:3,5,6, 4:8
 Taanit 2:6, 4:7
 Yevamot 1:3, 2:2,7, 3:4,5,6,7,9,10, 4:3,9, 9:3, 13:7, 14:3,4,5,6,7,8,9, 16:2
 Ketubot 2:6, 8:6, 11:5, 13:1,9,10
 Nedarim 7:8,9, 10:6
 Nazir 6:1,5, 8:1
 Sotah 1:8, 6:3
 Gittin 3:4, 9:4,5,6,7
 Bava Kamma 1:3, 2:5, 3:4,6,8,9,11, 4:1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8, 5:1,4
 Bava Metzia 1:1, 3:4, 5:5, 7:8, 9:11, 10:6
 Bava Batra 3:2, 9:6, 10:7
 Sanhedrin 10:2
 Shevuot 1:1, 3:1,2,3,4,7,9,10,11, 4:1,3,12, 5:1,2, 6:1
 Eduyot 1:1,2, 2:4,5,6,7,8, 3:8,10,12, 4:9
 Avodah Zarah 3:4,7, 4:7
 Pirkei Avot 1:2,9,10,15,17, 4:19, 5:7,8, 6:1
 Zevachim 3:6, 5:7
 Menachot 2:2, 3:3,6,7, 8:4, 9:1,2, 11:1,7,9, 13:9
 Chullin 2:4, 6:4, 7:2, 12:1
 Bekhorot 2:7, 3:4, 7:5, 8:4,5, 9:5
 Arakhin 4:4, 5:5, 6:1
 Keritot 1:1
 Meilah 2:6, 3:7, 6:2
 Middot 1:4,7, 5:3,4
 Kelim 3:1, 6:3,4, 22:8, 24:1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17, 27:10,11,12, 28:1,7, 29:2,7,8
 Oholot 1:1, 8:6, 14:5, 17:4,5, 18:2,3,4
 Negaim 4:4, 5:3, 8:6, 9:3, 10:2,4,6,7, 14:4,5,13
 Parah 2:4, 3:1, 4:2,3, 5:4,8,9, 7:11, 8:1, 9:3
 Tahorot 1:1, 4:6, 5:3,5,6,8
 Mikvaot 1:1, 6:3, 7:5
 Niddah 1:1, 6:12, 9:4,5,6
 Makhshirin 2:3, 3:1, 6:4
 Oktzin 1:2
ת
 Berakhot 4:1
 Peah 6:10
 Demai 5:11
 Kilayim 2:11, 9:4,6
 Sheviit 8:6
 Terumot 2:5, 10:2,4,5
 Maasrot 3:8,10, 4:2
 Maaser Sheni 2:3
 Orlah 2:10,15, 3:4,5
 Bikkurim 2:5
 Shabbat 3:2
 Pesachim 5:1
 Shekalim 3:4
 Yoma 2:5
 Sukkah 1:7
 Yevamot 4:6
 Nedarim 11:10
 Nazir 6:6,7
 Menachot 8:3
 Temurah 3:5
 Kelim 5:1,4,6,7,9,11, 8:5, 9:8, 10:7, 16:8, 17:17, 18:8, 19:7,9
 Oholot 4:2, 5:1
 Tahorot 3:7,8
 Niddah 5:3, 6:11, 10:1
 Makhshirin 6:5
 Yadayim 4:5
```

If you want to work by perek (as the question technically asked for and as [@kouty](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/9215/kouty) suggested to add), you can use the commented version of `selection`.  I'm out of characters, so I can't add that result here.

Comment: Wow. Thanks for posting this! Tizku l’Mitzvos.

Comment: Amen, thank you!  Use it in good health this week and then may it never be needed for such a purpose again.  בלע המות לנצח

Comment: Maybe valuable to select the x:1 only to answer precisely the question. But +1 for greet lesson

Comment: Boom!! Impressive!

Comment: @DonielF you might be interested in [my answer here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/111913/11532), which was inspired by this one and hence also came indirectly through your grandfather's zechus

Answer (score 4):

For those who prefer a printed page, [this](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=37951&st=&pgnum=516) is the the list in the back of the printed Mishnayos Zecher Chanoch on HebrewBooks.

[image: Page 1, Aleph through Ches]

[image: Page 2, Ches through Tav]

Comment: There should be a way to put the two pages of pdf in the answer itself, but that would be hard to do from my phone.

Comment: Done. It was surprisingly annoying; had to download the PDFs, convert to PNGs, then upload and format. No way to drop the PDFs directly into imgur. Also fixed some capitalization while I was at it.

Comment: Printed in all standard vilna shas in Brachot iirc